# Pycharm 2022 cannot connect to the docker service. It does not find it

Tags: python, docker, sockets, pycharm

I have Pycharm 2022 and when configuring a docker Python interpreter, Pycharm is not able to find the remote docker service, it seems that it cannot find it although the service is running (and I have the pro license):

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-11-07 16:22:43 CET; 22h ago TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
   Docs: https://docs.docker.com    Main PID: 1582 (dockerd)
  Tasks: 12
 Memory: 71.7M
 CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
         └─1582 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

I would appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appart from the official "solution" from Intelillj I find it easier with this workaround:

1. Help -> Find Action -> Registry
2. Disable `python.use.targets.api`
3. Try to configure the interpreter again

There is an official solution from Intelillj that you can check here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/6870884026898-Pycharm-2022-2-upgrade-and-Docker-issues