# PyCharm 2022 Can not connect to docker daemon even though it is running

Tags: docker, macos, pycharm

I am trying to configure my python interpreter to use docker but keep getting errors that it cannot connect to the docker daemon, even though I have docker desktop up and running.

[image: screenshot]

```
Connecting to Docker daemon…
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have tried solutions from:
[Docker is Running But Pycharm Cannot Connect to Docker Daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077725/docker-is-running-but-pycharm-cannot-connect-to-docker-daemon)
and
[Pycharm 2022 cannot connect to the docker service. It does not find it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362149/pycharm-2022-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-service-it-does-not-find-it)

I do not have to use sudo to run docker commands, and I tried disabling the use.targets.api and still got the same error.

If anyone has any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with pyCharm 2022.3 and Docker for Mac. Restarting Docker for Mac does not help, but after reboot of Macbook i got alert with password authorization request from Docker (about symlinking). Since authorization, everything is working properly.

Comment: The symlink (or lack of) seemed to be the issue. After updating docker it now prompts me for pass authz to symlink and now pycharm can connect to the docker daemon.